# How to process odd no. of SQL server tables from DBList through a generic job in Talend

Tags: talend

I am very new to Talend. And I was asked to 'How to process odd no. of SQL server tables from DBList through a generic job in Talend?' Could you please explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Talend is schema-based. If your tables schemas differ, you won't be able to proceed it with a single job. If schemas are the same, you only have to change the table name in your select query, using a context variable.

Comment: Thank you @Corentin for your response.I have updated my qustion, I meant to odd no. of table in the DBList. e.g I have ten tables in my list like 1,2,3,....10. I want write logic to process/consider odd no. of tables among them like 1,3,5,7 and 9.

Comment: Do you have the same schema between all those tables ?

Comment: No schema is diffrent. but for this process target source is file. Can't we use query like select * from TableName? @Corentin